# Proof of $v+U=x+W\implies U=W$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

Is the following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $v,x$ are vectors in $V$ and that $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $v+U = x+W$ then $U=W$

**Proof.** Evidently $v+0 = v\in v+U$ and since $v+U=x+W$ thus for some $w\in W$ it must be that $v = x+w$ which implies that $w=v-x\in W$ which may be equivalently stated as $v+W = x+W$ but from our original assumption $x+W = v+U$ therefore $v+W=v+U$ implying that $U=W$.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: @AndresMejia Can I ask how $v+U=v+W$ implies $U=W$?